# Como evitar o Lock do banco de dados utilizando Transaction do EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Eu tenho um método onde salvo várias classes e chamo outro método para fazer uma otimização em cima dessas classes, porém estou utilizando `Transaction`, para caso de algo de errado nessa otimização eu preciso dar `rollback`.

Transaction

```cs
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    using (var dbContextTransaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
```

Eu tentei trocar o isolationLevel assim:

```cs
using (var dbContextTransaction = 
                 context.Database.BeginTransaction(IisolationLevel.snapshot))
```

Porém mesmo assim ele continua dando `lock` no banco, gostaria de saber porque isso acontece e como eu faria para contornar essa situação, basicamente eu gostaria de fazer um `Optimistic concurrency control`, sem fazer checagem na hora de commitar, simplesmente a ultima versão é salva.

obs. utilizando de alguns comandos diretamente no banco de dados eu consegue o comportamento experado, porém me parece que o isolationLevel que eu seto no BeginTransaction não esta servindo de nada, caso alguém possa me explicar o funcionamento e me esclarer o que estou deixando passar, ficarei grato.

Comandos utilizados:

```cs
ALTER DATABASE [DB] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
ALTER DATABASE [DB] SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
ALTER DATABASE [DB] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;
ALTER DATABASE [DB] SET MULTI_USER
```

Comment: Qual é o banco?

Comment: Desculpe, é SQL SERVER

Comment: Não vejo nenhuma mágica possível... quando você seta o banco como Single_User, independente de transação, enquanto não chegar no Multi_User, o banco de dados não aceitará novas conexões